# how to download an archived branch in perforce

Tags: perforce, archive

There is a branch that was archived in our perforce server, but I don't know how to download those files. Even if the only way to get those files is to unarchive it that's fine too (I can get the branch unarchived), but I don't even know how to do that.

How do I download files from an archived branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean archived as in 'p4 archive'?

If so, consult 'p4 restore' to make the files available again.